# PasswordResetConfirmView is getting skipped and PasswordResetDoneView is shown directly

Tags: python, django

I was trying to use the standard django password reset, but instead of getting directed to the `PasswordResetConfirmView` I'm directly directed to the `PasswordResetDoneView` the code is below (I didn't put the html as it doesn't really matter and would just make the question longer)

urls.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
urlpatterns = [
path('password-reset/',auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='users/password_reset.html'),name='password_reset'),
    path('password-reset-confirm/<uidb64>/<token>',auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='users/password_reset_confirm.html'),name='password_reset_confirm.html'),
    path('password-reset/done/',auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='users/password_reset_done.html'),name='password_reset_done')
```

]

Comment: What do you mean redirected to? When you click on the link in the email? How does the link look?

Comment: there is no link generated but theres a message saying that it has been generated actually it is supposed to take the user to the PasswordResetConfirmView but it isnt